# STM32L476RG HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback never call

Tags: stm32

I'm curently working on a projet with a STM32F334 and a STM32L476RG and I have a problem to making them talking with eachother. I'm using a DMA global interrupt like explained [here](https://controllerstech.com/uart-dma-with-idle-line-detection/).

I noticed a difference into the 'main.c' of my both projects:

- With the F334: `MX_DMA_Init()` is done before `MX_USART2_UART_Init()`
- With the L476RG: It's the opposite.

I tryed to inverse them and it works but only once... (at start)
So how could I tell the code generator to initialize the `DMA` before my `USART2`?

```c
void HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint16_t size) {

    if (huart->Instance == USART2) {

        rs485_send_data(huart, g_rs485Input, size);

        HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA(&huart2, g_rs485Input, RS485_INPUT_LENGTH);
        __HAL_DMA_DISABLE_IT(&hdma_usart2_rx, DMA_IT_HT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I has experimented same issue.
I build the same example for **NUCLEO-L073RZ** but at first, the function ***HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback*** was never called.

Then I read your question, and I set the order as You say

> MX_DMA_Init() before MX_USART2_UART_Init()

(like in the controllerstech example). I reset the uart transmisor and debug again NUCLEO board.Then I had one breakpoint in ***HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback***, so the program entered into the function an was stoped in the breakpoint. AS you say, the program enter in the breakpoint once in ever start.

So, I tried deleting this breakpoint in order to do not stop the program in debugging. After that, I watch in Live Expressions MainBuf, RxBuf, isOK, oldPos, newPos and it seems that is working perfectly.

Has you tried without breakpoints? Another way, you can try not debugging, running the program in normal mode and verify turning on one led or writing in other uart port.

Is not the first time that I have experienced irregular running of the program in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had a setup where I was using Lab View to communicate with the Nucleo-STM32F401RE over UART, I was having the same issue as you described.

The solution in my case was to make sure the parity bit was set to none, for some reason if it's set to something else it caused the behavior you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across the same issue. It took me a while to realise, but in debug mode the `HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback` is never called. Couldn't find a way to fix this, unfortunately. However, my code did run fine when running normally.